# Java: How to get openjdk8u60 sources

Tags: java

I understand that it seems to be very easy question but I can't find. When I do
`hg clone http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u` I get sources for openjdk8u40 but I need openjdk8u60. How to get them?

Comment: The first description on the OpenJDK jdk8u page is "Added tag jdk8u60-b11 for changeset db15b96c7812".  It appears that jdk8u60 has been tagged.

Comment: @Gilbert Le Blanc Anyway I don't undestand how to get sources.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My receipe is:

1. Install mercurial to `/usr/bin`.
2. Go to directory you want to download jdk8 sources.
3. Run there: `hg clone http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/`
4. `cd jdk8u/`
5. `chmod +x get_source.sh`
6. `LANG=C`
7. `./get_source.sh`
8. Make some coffee.
9. Read built-in *README-builds.html* (located in the `jdk8u` as stated in this example) in order to build sources from received data, depending on your system.
10. Enjoy.

Comment: I was going to point out exactly this. http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/file/6ff963c0dd41/get_source.sh is a bash script which downloads the hg forest of java source code (but I never used Mercurial, so just guessing what it does)

Comment: Mercurial is another CVS like git or svn. Indeed `get_source.sh` use it to download all jdk sources.

Comment: The question asks to get source for openjdk8u60. Does this get sources for openjdk8u60?

Answer (score 2):

if you browse the hg repository you find that the organization is the following one:
there are different repositories for different versions and there is one repository for the "dev version"
at http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u you find the current stable version that is tagged jdk8u60-b12 so every new commit in this branch represent the current jdk8u60 stable version. if you want to grab the dev version of the same jdk you have to clone the repository at http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u-dev/